# SFTP transfer a file(xml) success to remote server, but the file has been rewritten by a path, joomla

Tags: php, xml, joomla, sftp, phpseclib

I had a joomla website, using SFTP transfer a XML file to a remote server. Remote server received the file but the content of file changed to the path of where the XML file located in the web server.

---

```
 $web_directory = "upload/xml/";
 $web_directory .=   $ref .".xml";
 $fp = fopen($path_dir,'wb');
 $write = fwrite($fp,$xml_output);
 fclose($fp);
 // file saved successfully, in the upload/xml/ names $ref.xml such as rt34458r2.xml.
 include '/vendor/autoload.php';

 $remote_directory = '/im/XML/';
 $remote_directory .=   $ref .".xml";

 $sftp = new \phpseclib\Net\SFTP('remote server address',22);
 if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password'))
{
    exit('SFTP Login Failed');
    echo $sftp->getSFTPLog();
 }else{

    echo $sftp->pwd();
    $sftp->put($remote_directory, $web_directory, NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);
 }
```

XML file created and saved successful in the web server (name such as rt34458r2.xml). and the file transferred to remote server also works (same name ). But the content in the XML file changed to "upload/xml/rt34458r2.xml" which is not same content in the file of web server.

please help!!!!

Comment: _“But the content in the XML file changed to "upload/xml/rt34458r2.xml" which is not same content in the file of web server.”_ - did you actually verify that by downloading the file from that other server? Or are you just looking at something the browser shows when you try to request the URL?

Comment: I verified the file by downloading from remote server. opened then content changed.

Comment: What is `$path_dir`? If that is the local file you are trying to write to and then upload afterwards, why is it a different variable then you use later when uploading the file? You might have to call `clearstatcache`, so that PHP realizes that the file contents have been changed (not sure if $sftp->put is immune to that.)

Comment: Sorry CBroe, it is $fp = fopen($web_directory,'wb');

Comment: Does the file exist before already? (And if so, does it in that case actually contain the file name as file content?) Have you tried `clearstatcache`? What do you get when you read the file content directly before you try to put it onto the other server (`echo file_get_contents('filename');`) ...?

Comment: Hi CBroe, Where to add clearstatcache? above $sftp=new...? the file(before to put it onto the other server) has the content what I need. such as <?xml version=....< order data>.....

Comment: _“the file(before to put it onto the other server) has the content what I need”_ - did you test this from _within_ the script? If so, then `clearstatcache` likely won’t help, because then the underlying issue doesn’t seem to be caching in the first place.

Comment: "did you test this from within the script?"No! I did not test within the script. but I download the file open and see.

Comment: But that’s the whole point, we need to verify whether _your script_ can read the correct file content at this point already ...

Comment: I see what you mean now! website create this XML file. and then read. So Yes! my script can read the file correctly.

Comment: If I understand the documentation correctly, then if `NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE` was not passed as third parameter, _then_ the SFTP script would explicitly write the _string_ content of the second parameter into the file - that would explain the issue, I guess. But your script does seem to be passing it - sure you got full PHP error reporting enabled, and are not missing an undefined constant warning here or anything like that?

Comment: "
If I understand the documentation correctly, then if NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE was not passed as third parameter, then the SFTP script would explicitly write the string content of the second parameter into the file " this is what I thought. Let me digging up the log file. will update as soon I can

Comment: I am using phpseclib V3, looks like the NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE is not exist in the SFTP.php.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution here. The problem of my code is: I updated phpseclib to V3 (latest version), and should use SOURCE_LOCAL_FILE instead of NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE. So I amended my code:

```
}else{

echo $sftp->pwd();
$sftp->put($remote_directory, $web_directory, \phpseclib\Net\SFTP::SOURCE_LOCAL_FILE);}
```

or

```
$sftp->put($remote_directory, $web_directory, $sftp::SOURCE_LOCAL_FILE);
```

Answer (score 0):

or

```
$sftp->put($remote_directory, $web_directory, $sftp::SOURCE_LOCAL_FILE);
```